# Creating a list of terms from another in Python

Tags: python, list

I am troubled with the following problem.

I have a list with symmetric items, e.g., `k = [-1,1,-2,2,-3,3]`. Depending of the number of items (`Ni`), I would like to create another list, `e`,  using it in the following way: each item of list `k` can generate in the max. 2 items in the list `e`, but there is a “order” of filling of the list `e`.

For example, if we have `Ni=4` then there is 4 items in `e`. I will fill `e` according the following way: each item of `k` can ‘support’ 2 values. As the second value is filled only after its symmetric and corresponding value be filled, as we have 4 in this example, the 1st item of `e` is `-1`, 2nd would be `1`, the 3rd, `-1` again, and finally the 4th would be `1`.

If I have `Ni=5`, the fifth element would be `-2`, 6th would be `2`, 7th , `-2` and the eighth `2`. The examples below illustrate this.

My initial code is:

```
k=[-1,1,-2,2,-3,3]
Ni=input("Ni: ")
e=[]
temp = 1
for i in k:
    e.append(i)
    temp+=1
    if temp>Ni:
        break
---
```

And then I get

```
e = [-1,1,-2,2,-3]
```

and this result of course is not exactly what I want. The examples below illustrate better what I mean.

Example 0: `Ni = 1`
The list would be:

```
e=[-1]
```

Example 1: `Ni = 2`
The list ‘e’ would be:

```
e=[-1,1]
```

Example 2: `Ni = 3`

```
e=[-1,1,-1]
```

Ex. 3: `Ni = 4`

```
e=[-1,1,-1,1]
```

Ex. 4: `Ni = 5`

```
e=[-1,1,-1,1,-2]
```

Ex. 5: `Ni = 6`

```
e=[-1,1,-1,1,-2,2]
```

Ex. 6: `Ni = 7`

```
e=[-1,1,-1,1,-2,2,-2]
```

Ex.7: `Ni = 8`

```
e=[-1,1,-1,1,-2,2,-2,2]
```

Thanks in advance for any help, ideas, suggestions, etc!

Comment: how does `Ex. 3: Ni = 4` work? Or any of them, where are the values coming from?

Comment: Why do you have no code?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham:  “Ni=4” then there is 4 items in ‘e’.  I will fill ‘e’ according the following way: each item of ‘k’ can ‘support’ 2 values, but the second value is filled only after its symmetric and corresponding value be filled. In this example: as we have 4, the 1st item of ‘e’ is ‘-1’, 2nd would be ‘1’, the 3rd, ‘-1’ again, and finally (the fourth one) would be ‘1’. If I would have Ni=5, the fifth element would be ‘-2’, 6th would be ‘2’, 7th , ‘-2’ and the eighth ‘2’.

Comment: @pheel09,add that to your question and any code you have tried

Comment: @pheel09 I attempted to answer your question, but your description of how the list is ordered does not match the ordering you have in your above comment. In a list, unlike a set or other data type, order matters so please keep it consistent

Comment: ok @PadraicCunningham, thanks, I added this text to my question.

Comment: @BadKarma I changed my example above. believe is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ni = int(input("Select number of items: "))
k = [-1,1,-2,2,-3,3]
if Ni <= len(k) + 2:
    if Ni <= 2:
        e = k[0:Ni]
    else:
        e = [x for x in sorted(k[0:2]*2) + k[2:len(k)]][0:Ni]
```

Comment: Hi @BadKarma, this works for my intention but unfortunately it is absurdely advanced to my begginer skills...could you put this in other format? obs: i've looked for materials related to your code but am having difficulties to find a good one...thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
def fill(k, Ni): 
    return sorted(list(itertools.islice(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(itertools.chain.from_iterable((k[i], k[i+1])*2 for i in range(0,len(k),2)), )), 0, Ni)), key=lambda i:(abs(i), i))
```

Or, a slightly more readable version:

```
def fill(k, Ni): 
    return sorted(list(
               itertools.islice(
                   itertools.chain.from_iterable(
                       zip(
                           itertools.chain.from_iterable((k[i], k[i+1])*2 for i in range(0,len(k),2)), 
                       )
                   ),
                   0, Ni
               )
            ), key=lambda i:(abs(i), i))
```